# Implementing IntelliSense support for custom language (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I wan to implement IntelliSense support for custom language. Actually it is a customize version of C++. i.e the methods resides in separate files

So my main class is like followings and it has import file MyClassMethods which has all the methods.

```
public class MyClass {
    @import MyClassMethods
    // my code goes here
}
```

So my MyClassMethods fiel looks like following and it has two methods,

```
public void testMethod1() {
}
public void testMethod2() {
}
```

Then at the end I want to have IntelliSense features when I working on MyClass. Example when I put dot character on that class in a required place I want to have testMethod1() and testMethod2() in the IntelliSense menu.

Is this possible to achieve and if so how can I achieve this?

Comment: The C++ language services are extremely unlikely to work with this (unless you use projection buffers, which they may also not support).  You will probably need to rewrite them from scratch.  Good luck.

Comment: I was looking at CompletionTest walk-though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx   
There it uses ICompletionSource interface. 
So there I don't have a way of directly dealing with language properties (such as types, tokens etc..). 
i.e to find the type of the variable which is related to dot character. 

So in this case I might need to implement kind of a language parser as well. 
Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the raw editor APIs it's assumed you've parsed your file and done all of that. There are no shortcuts here -- this is hard.

Comment: What do you mean by raw editor API? Meanwhile I am implementing things based on above mentioned complete test walk-through. Anyway I found this as well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165450(v=vs.120).aspx . Parent article is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166360(v=vs.120).aspx . Do you think this is the proper way to go instaded of above mentioned 'complete test walk-through' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx